# Using browser.webRequest on a createObjectURL url match

Tags: javascript, webrequest, firefox-addon-webextensions

Can an object url from window.URL.createObjectURL be used in a browser.webRequest url match to intercept a download request of a url blob?

If so, how is the match written?

The object urls have the form of blob:null/839459f5-7f47-4548-986c-5830fdeaa009; all seem to start with "blob:null".

For the match

```
<scheme>://<host><path>,
```

I haven't been able to find anything that works to catch the download of the object url.

I've tried

```
"<all_urls">, "*://*/*", "blob:null/*".
```

I can catch the browser.downloads.onCreated event but nothing with webRequest. The webRequest statement is as follows.

```
browser.webRequest.onBeforeSendHeaders.addListener(

 listener,

 { urls : ["<all_urls>"] },

["blocking"] );
```

And, the permissions in the manifest.json are:

```
  "permissions" : [ "downloads", "webRequest", "webRequestBlocking", "<all_urls>" ],
```

Any idea what I'm doing wrong or not doing?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, Blob URIs are not a network request. It's the same with cached pages, you can't intercept those either.

Comment: Thanks. If perform an XMLHttpRequest() on a blob URL it returns '200' 'OK'.

Comment: That is correct, however cached resources or data URIs are also returned by XHR. webRequest only handles actions that trigger an actual network request, which is not the case for Blobs (or cached things or data URIs). Blobs are generated by JS and have an URI so you can use them with all APIs in the web platform that work with URLs. In conclusion, being able to load something with XHR does not mean it will get passed through webRequest.